# @Scheduled thread is got lost while importing files from FTP

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I have @Scheduled with fixed delay method that imports files from FTP. Usually it works fine, but often it got lost somewhere in FTP, in logs i see my app start to import file, in FTP logs i see it disconnect my worker. What is possible reason of this, is there some timeout which for sure will disconnect my worker from FTP? Thanks.

Comment: can you show if there is any error message?

Comment: There are no errors, my FTPworker writes in log - it starts to import file and that's it, no more info writed in log, no exceptions, no errors. It is possible reason goes from FTP side. So i need timeout which will make me deadly sure i will be disconnected from FTP any way. Thanks.

Comment: I use this code @Scheduled(fixedDelay = DELAY)
 public void monitor()
 {
  LOGGER.debug(LOG_PREFIX + "Start monitor");
  check();
  LOGGER.debug(LOG_PREFIX + "End monitor");
 }

Comment: What can help to finish execution of task for sure any way?